# How to fix "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

When I'm fetching vast amount of data (in form of videos) from cache the app responds after a long delay.

How do I resolve or fix it?

[image: Logcat: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread]

Comment: Do this process in AsysncTask, it will reduce works on main thread.

Comment: Describe with code.

Comment: do this with asynctask or service. Search for example you will find a lot.

Comment: Have you tried  android:largeHeap="true" in application tag inside AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Comment: this question is so open , you should refer the tons of android documents about threading before asking a question

https://medium.com/@maheswaranapk/android-threading-introduction-90e91e196600

Comment: @NileshPanchal no i have no tried this let me check sir

Comment: @NileshPanchal sir i have already use this command android:largeheap="true"

Comment: but issue have not fixed. how to fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While performing long running or computation heavy tasks, you should prefer doing it on a background thread (i.e, separate from the UI thread).

You will see ANRs on the app if the UI thread is kept busy for more than 5 seconds, but even for less than 5 seconds there will be a noticeable lag and delay of user actions (click, scroll) and a similar message in logs as you are seeing (**Choreographer : Skipped XXX frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**).

Some of the ways to such perform tasks on background thread are :

- [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)
- [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask)
- [Java Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread) / [Android HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread)
- [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService)

Also, be careful while updating the UI from a background thread as Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe.

---

Edit :

For off-loading tasks from main thread, you can also use :

- [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html)
- [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: thanks sir but one thing is that my app is working fine when using this background task but data will show little bet time now fastly show.

Comment: is it possible that app showup data little bet and when im scrolling down data fetch.

Comment: for such a behaviour you will have to implement something like **Pagination, Lazy loading, Android's Paging library etc**

Comment: how to use pagination or lazy loading android any idea sir?

Comment: for implementing  pagination or lazy loading you can do something like this - suppose on start up, your screen shows 20 items, then you should first fetch about 30 items and then keep fetching more items subsequently. you can set the number of records to be fetched on start up and subsequent fetches depending on your usage.

Comment: ok sir but how to fetch startup screen 30 item fetch in recycler view then user scroll down and fetch 30 30 items. if it is possible then how to do it?

Comment: you can keep a service running for fetching items, along with that try using Android's LiveData (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and Paging (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)