# How much is too much work for the main thread to handle? Some questions regarding the threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-threading

I have a background in Java and recently, I'm learning about Java in Android so the question might seem to be overwhelming for a newcomer like me. Anyway, here are the questions (in *italic*).

I created a project using a template (Phone and Tablet - Empty Activity), then used Layout Editor to add 2 Plain Text to the GUI. After that, I added some code to **MainActivity.java** (there is nothing else in the class).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText equation = findViewById(R.id.textEquation);
    equation.setEnabled(false);

    EditText result = findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    result.setEnabled(false);

}

public void onBtnClick(View theView){

    EditText equation = findViewById(R.id.textEquation);
    EditText result = findViewById(R.id.textResult);

}
```

When I ran the program, I got this warning: `I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` As the answers shown in these links: [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread) and [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. how to fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625433/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread-how-to-fixed-it). This might not be a real issue as I'm using an emulator and the code/resource are from a template, which might not be optimal.

*However, what exactly determines the term **"too much work"** here?* When I comment out the two lines in `onBtnClick`, the warning goes away. Although I'm using an emulator, `findViewById()` is considerably "heavy" enough to generate the warning. **I know [60 fps (16ms per frame)](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render) is the standard, but it still does not answer my question.**

<s>Besides, can someone simplify the main thread/method doing right now (in my case)? I'm aware that the `main` class/thread in Android is different than in regular Java programming (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293329/where-is-main-in-android#:%7E:text=In%20the%20case%20of%20Android,of%20a%20main()%20method.)).</s>

*Concept wise, is the main threads completely different than threads for UI (like using `invokeLater` in Java Swing)?* I guess it is, as the Google document suggests ["As such, the main thread is also sometimes called the UI thread. However, under special circumstances, an app's main thread might not be its UI thread; for more information, see Thread annotations."](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

---

**Update**

- (09/30) For the question that I striked through, now that I've read more about [Activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), I start to have a sense of what's going underneath. **However, I'm still finding answers for the two italic question.**

Comment: Basically, everything that takes longer than 16ms (one frame) is too much.

Comment: @Henry As you said, the standard seems to be 60 fps as in [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render). However, the main point of my question is about determining the workload and threshold of main thread. 

As my example shown, only the inclusion of two lines in `onBtnClick` is enough to make a change in rendering performance, even nothing is calling them.